# Graphing polar equation $r\sin \theta = 1$?

Tags: polar-coordinates

> How would you graph $r \sin \theta = 1$?

I know that $r\sin \theta$ is equal to $y$, but the place where I'm told to graph this function on is a polar graph. How should I go about this?

Comment: It seems like you see that this is the same as $y=1$, which is a horizontal line passing through $(0,1)$. You can draw the same thing on a polar grid.

Comment: @applestointegrals. Are you essentially asking how to produce a graph on a graphing device?

Comment: There is a lot of material on the web about graphing polar equations. Just Google and you will find nice videos as well as explanations. This will help you to not only graph the above equation, but several others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Milo is correct about this particular graph, let me pretend it isn't that easy so as to give you an idea how to proceed with this in general:

$(x, y) = (r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$, and the equation you want to graph is $r \sin \theta = 1$ which solves to $r = 1/\sin \theta$. so:
$$(x, y) = \left(\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}, \frac{\sin \theta}{\sin \theta}\right) = (\tan \theta, 1)$$

Now, choose various values of $\theta$, and plot the corresponding points $(x, y)$, and there is your graph. (Okay, I'm old-school. This is how you plot it by hand.)

Comment: or, if you have polar coordinate paper, you don't even need to go Cartesian! B-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that equation can be rewritten as $\ r  = \dfrac{1}{\sin \theta}$.
Therefore you can explicitly compute the value of $r$ for each value of $\,\theta$, except for $\theta = \pi n$, in which case you can compute a limit.

For example,  for $\theta=\pi/2$ you get $r = 1$,  for $\theta=\pi/3$ $r = 2/\sqrt{3}$, for  $\theta=3\pi/4$  $r = \sqrt{2}$, etc.